# Remove some text with shell scripts?

Tags: shell, scripting, cygwin

I wanted to get some help on how I can use cygwin, which has bash to shell script the following:

I have a txt file that contains the following:

```
action "action1"
  reset
  type xformbin
  http-method-limited POST
  http-method-limited2 POST
exit

action "action2"
  reset
  admin-state disabled
  type results
  http-method-limited POST
  http-method-limited2 POST
exit

action "action3"
  reset
  admin-state disabled
  type setvar
  http-method-limited POST
  http-method-limited2 POST
exit
```

I was hoping a shell script could be written to remove the block where admin-state = disabled?

So, I'm hoping I can iterate through the txt file and if admin-state = disabled, remove everything between "action" and "exit" from that particular block.

I would expect the following final results from the sample text:

```
action "action1"
  reset
  type xformbin
  http-method-limited POST
  http-method-limited2 POST
exit
```

Thank you.

Comment: `sed '/disabled/,/exit/ d' infile`? Maybe write the output to another location until you're confident it's doing what you want. I'm leery of jumping straight to `-i`.

Comment: thank you @PaulHodges although with that, I get:

action "action2" reset 

action "action2" reset admin-state enabled type xform
http-method GET http-method-limited POST http-method-limited2 POST exit

action "action3" reset

... any idea to get rid of the residual "action" to "reset" parts?

Comment: When I run the command I get exactly what you list above as the result you said you wanted. Please edit your post to clarify what you hoped to get.

Comment: @PaulHodges Ah, I see what happened... my file has line breaks ... let me update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want the whole block ignored if it has 'disabled' in the middle, but printed if it does not.

```
sed -n '
  /action/,/exit/ {
  /action/ { x; d; }
  H;
  /exit/ { x;
    /disabled/ d;
    p;         d;
  }
}' x
```

This will do nothing unless in a block from `action` to `exit`. In those -

If a line has `action`, store it and delete the pattern space to trigger the next read.

Otherwise append the line to the stored hold space.

If the line had `exit`,

- swap the hold space into the pattern space
- if the collected pattern has `disabled`, delete it to trigger reading the next record;
- if not, print it, then delete it to trigger  reading the next record.

The output:

```
$: sed -n '
  /action/,/exit/ {
    /action/ { x; d; }
    H;
    /exit/ { x;
      /disabled/ d;
      p;         d;
    }
  }' infile
action "action2"
reset
admin-state enabled
type xform
http-method GET
http-method-limited POST
http-method-limited2 POST exit
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you @PaulHodges 
Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 0):

do you have perl?

```
local $/="exit";
while (<>) {
    print if not /admin-state disabled/;
}
```

Comment: Should that be `print "$_\exit"` or some such? Won't it lose the "exit" otherwise?

Comment: no, it prints matching paragraph (which includes the "exit"), did you run it?

Comment: You didn't *strip* it. My bad. :) Been a while since I've written perl, getting out of practice, lol